# Need help to compare a SpecFlow table with a DataTable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, specflow, system.data.datatable

I am trying to use SpecFlow BDD testing with data collected from an SQL Analysis services cube (got ideas from this article https://notesfromthelifeboat.com/post/analysis-services-2-testing/)

Most of the things work, but the final step where I want to compare an expected result set with a result from a dax query, I run into some problems. The code below shows the two most interesting methods. GivenIHaveMadeTheFollowingFilterSelection(Table table) creates a System.Data.DataTable object with some rows, and I want to compare this object with the result set from the SpecFlow Table as described below. The important things happen inside the ThenTheDataShouldBeDisplayedAsFollows(Table table) method. I want to compare the Specflow table with the system.data.Datatable in the easiest way. I believe there is a way converting the DataTable object so I can use Specflow assist methods comparing in one line (I hope). My code is experimenting with many possibilities but I hope I can make use of table.CompareToSet() so I don't need to loop and compare row by row (then I need sorting).

I hope you understand my problem and can guide me through this

Regards Geir

| Date | Order count | Total amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 2 | 150.00 |
| 2020-01-03 | 1 | 750.00 |
| 2020-01-04 | 2 | 130.50 |

```
  [

   [Given(@"I have made the following filter selection:")]
        public void GivenIHaveMadeTheFollowingFilterSelection(Table table)
        {
            var query = @"EVALUATE SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
                'Date'[Date],
                FILTER('Date', 'Date'[Year] = 2020),
                ""Order count"", [CountOfOrders],                   
                ""Total amount"", [Total Amount]
            )";
            this.dataTable = _tabularHelper.GetDataTable(query);
         }

    [Then(@"the data should be displayed as follows:")]
    public void ThenTheDataShouldBeDisplayedAsFollows(Table table)
    {
        int index = 0;
        var expectedRows = table.CreateSet<WeeklySales>() ;

        var collection = ConvertToTankReadings(this.dataTable);

        Assert.IsTrue(table.RowCount == this.dataTable.Rows.Count);

    
        table.CompareToSet<WeeklySales>(collection);

        foreach (WeeklySales expectedRow in expectedRows)
        {
            DataRow row = this.dataTable.Rows[index++];
            var tt = expectedRow.TotalAmount;
            var tt1 = expectedRow.Date;
            var tt2 = expectedRow.OrderCount;
            //Assert.AreEqual(expectedRow.TotalAmount, row["[Total Amount]"]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the `Then` step where you need to make the assertion? The answer will likely depend on the column names chosen in the scenario.

Comment: And also include the `WeeklySales` class.